# Doctrine2 QueryBuilder: How to filter out entities having zero count for a OneToMany

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, associations, one-to-many, query-builder

In my Dymfony2 / Doctrine2 application, I have a *oneToMany* relation between an object and its children.

I want to select all objects which have no children.

I'm stuck with various errors: *SingleValuedAssociationField expected, Cannot add Having sth on non result variable*, etc.

```
$queryBuilder = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('object')
    ->leftJoin('object.children', 'children')
    ->andWhere('children IS NULL')
    // tested with a parameter, with addselect COUNT(children) and 0 condition, etc.
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a selector called `SIZE()`, which should do the trick. More to read [here.](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions)

Try something like this:

```
$this
    ->createQueryBuilder('object')
    ->leftJoin('object.children', 'children')
    ->where('SIZE(object.children) = 0')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: nice ! that is totally what I was looking for ! thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What if you want to use the SIZE with a filter, for example if you want to get the objects that have more than 1 children with more than 5 years:

```
 $this

->createQueryBuilder('object')

->leftJoin('object.children', 'children', 'WITH', 'children.age > 5')

->where('SIZE(object.children) > 1') /*Here I can't put the previous filter join*/

->getQuery()

->getResult();
```

This way, the SIZE is applied to all the collection and not only for children who have more than 5 years.

Thanks